# Fixed and fluid layout html

Tags: html, css, layout

I have to make fixed + fluid layout, basic scheme of it is here - http://cdn.joxi.ru/uploads/prod/2014/09/05/b77/ee2/4696a3b3738ea85f3d45a325e0fd31109624cfad.jpg

Structure of HTML is:

```
header
.leftcolumn > aside
.rightcolumn
```

CSS is:

```
header { width: 940px; margin: auto; }
.leftcolumn { float: left; }
aside { width: 200px; }
.rightcolumn { overflow: hidden; }
```

The point is to make this construction centered: header has to be in the center of layout, aside has to appear at the left edge of header and to be inside of .leftcolumn

Now I've done this with JS:

```
function innerFunc() {
    var marginLeft;
    marginLeft = $('header').css('margin-left');
    $('aside').css('marginLeft', marginLeft);
}

innerFunc();
$(window).resize(function() {
    innerFunc();
})
```

But it would be great to make it JS-free. Any suggestions?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7ns4uzpg/

Comment: Solution is found :) Long story short: it was done by extra (10000px) padding and negative (-10000px) margins.